# Any minimal WAP dynamical system is distal

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

I'm trying to show that any minimal WAP dynamical system $(X, G)$ is almost periodic. By Ellis's joint continuity theorem, it suffices to show that any minimal WAP system is distal. There are many references that prove this under the additional assumption that $X$ is metrizable.

I feel like there should be some slick enveloping semigroup proof of this. For instance if $G$ is abelian, we can do the following. Say $x\neq y\in X$ are proximal. Then there is some $p\in E(X)$ with $xp = yp$. We may suppose that $p$ is a minimal idempotent, so that $Xp$ is a proper subset of $X$. By WAP, $p$ is continuous, so $Xp\subsetneq X$ is compact, and as $G$ is abelian, $Xp$ is a subflow of $X$, contradicting minimality.

Comment: Hello Andy, I'm guessing that this is the first time you've posted on here. Your question isn't very accessible to people who are not absolutely in the exact area of your question. It's generally thought to be polite to explain the definitions (what is a WAP dynamical system) etc.

Comment: A system is WAP iff every member of the enveloping semigroup is continuous. A system is distal iff there are no non-trivial proximal pairs; $(x,y)$ is non-trivial proximal iff $x\neq y$ and there is some $p\in E(X)$ with $xp = yp$. (It may also be worth clarifying that I'm applying functions on the right).

Comment: Thanks Andy - maybe put this in the body of the question?